# How to remove margin from between images on React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and trying to build a simple app that displays four images on the screen with Touchable function however there is margin between pictures and setting margin:0 and padding:0 are not helping at all.

What might be a solution?

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <SafeAreaView>

          {listItems.map(
            (item) => (
              console.log(item.pic),
              (
                <View>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClickPic}>
                  <ImageBackground
                    style={styleImage.container}
                    source={item.pic}
                  >
                    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                  </ImageBackground>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )
            )
          )}

      </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styleImage = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: "30%",
    width: "30%",
    padding:0,
    margin:0,
  },
});
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWf2l.png): [image: Code with Emulator Preview]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Replace ImageBackground with Image
and add one property to it resizeMode='cover', it will pull the image to ends of image area

```
          {listItems.map(
            (item) => (
              console.log(item.pic),
              (
                <View>
                 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClickPic}>
                  <View>
                   <Image
                    resizeMode="cover" // or 'stretch'
                    style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }}
                    source={item.pic}
                    />

                   <View style={{ position: "absolute", zIndex: 9 }}>
                    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                   </View>
                  </View>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )
            )
          )}
      </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
```

Style as your requirement